# Node Lambda: MySQL query never runs

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Testing with Postman, I'll try to make this as clear as possible, please advise if this is not making sense.

I have a Lambda that uses MySQL RDS database on AWS and works fine locally when accessing the database on AWS. After successfully getting a JWT from an `auth` endpoint I try to hit the `login` endpoint and I get a `502 Bad Gateway`. Using the CloudWatch logs I can trace the failure to right before the login query runs. I've confirmed that my MySQL config is correct and that I have a connection to the database. The lambda and the database are in the same region `DB: us-east-1f`, `lambda: us-east-1`.

I've confirmed the OPTIONS and POST request methods for this endpoint both are set up with CORS enabled in the API Gateway. I'm using my serverless.yml to set `cors: true` on all the endpoints even though I'm using `app.use(cors())` in my index file.

The error message for the 502 is, `{"message": "Internal server error"}`

Here is the point of failure in my code:

```
'use strict';

const mysql = require('./index');

module.exports = {
  loginSql: async (email, password) => {
    // MAKES IT HERE AND THE PARAMS ARE CORRECT
    try {
      console.log('IN TRY %%%%%%%%%%%%%%');
      // SEEMS TO DIE HERE
      const results = await mysql.query({
        sql: `SELECT 
        id, first_name, last_name, email 
        FROM users 
        WHERE email = ? 
        AND password = ?`,
        timeout: 50000,
        values: [email, password],
      });
      // NEVER MAKES IT HERE /////////
      console.log('QUERY RAN %%%%%%%%%%%%');
      mysql.end();
      if (results.length < 1) return false;
      return results;
    } catch (error) {
      // DOESN'T THROW ERROR
      console.log('LOGIN DB ERROR', error);
      throw new Error('LOGIN DB ERROR THROWN', error);
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: What is `mysql` here?

Comment: It's the `serverless-mysql` object returned when I make my connection to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created the exact same use case in that I have a LAMBDA function written in Java querying data from a MySQL RDS instance. It works perfectly.

Here is your issue:

To connect to the RDS instance from a Lambda function, y**ou must set the inbound rules using the same security group as the RDS Instance**. For details, [How do I configure a Lambda function to connect to an RDS instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-lambda-to-an-rds-instance/).

[image]

Comment: Nice call, at work I normally set the VPC and Security Groups in my serverless.yml file, but for some reason on this personal project I left them out.